# Multiple select by array

Tags: php, arrays

I have:

```
$selectedItem = '100,200,300';
```

And mysql load:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="product_id">
   <?php
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id");
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
      echo '<option value="$row[id]">$name</option>';
   }
   ?>
</select>
```

And I need **$selectedItem** (three values) to be:

```
<option value="$row[id]" selected>$row[id]</option>
```

How can I do that? I just can't find the solution when the **selectedItem** more than 1.

Comment: isn't this php? somebody pls use the right tags!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make your `$selectedItem` variable an array (and name it plural since it can have multiple values; just my added preference =P):

```
$selectedItems = array(100, 200, 300);
```

Doing this, you'll be able to check if the current row's `id` is in the array or not (with `in_array()`) and then "select" that row:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $selected = in_array($row['id'], $selectedItems) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
    echo '<option value="' . $row[id] . '"' . $selected . '>' . $row['id'] . '</option>';
}
```

Alternatively, if you can't "define" your list of selected items as an array and you will *only* have a comma-separated string, you can use `explode()` to turn it into an array:

```
$selectedItems = explode(',', $selectedItem);
```

This will split the `$selectedItem` variable by commas into an array stored into `$selectedItems` (usable with the above code).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
     if ( str_pos( $selectedItem.',' , $row[id].',' ) !== false) {
        $sel = 'selected';
     } else {
        $sel = '';
     }
     echo "<option value='$row[id]' $sel>$row[id]</option>";
}
```